# Update item in list Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to implement when i am press button 'changenName', all of added and displayed name will change to 'test2'? I have to use nameList.forEach() or nameList.where()?

```
  String name = 'test'; 
  List<String> nameList = List<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: nameList.length == 0
                ? Text('0')
                : Column(
                    children: nameList
                        .map(
                          (e) => Text(e),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                nameList.add(name);
              });
            },
            child: Text('add'),
          ),
           RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                        //??
              });
            },
            child: Text('changeName'),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Not clear. Kindly add a screenshot of the current output and your expected output

Comment: I will try to explain what I would like . when i am to  press 'add',  the 'name' was added to list and displayed. let's say, i  added to list 2 'name' and it was displayed on te screen 'test' , 'test'. I would like to press on 'changeName' and this 'test' 'test' will change to 'test2' 'test2'

Comment: Ah I see. It's clear. I'll add my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function for updating the name which takes a name to be changed as an argument and onPressed you can call that function inside setState.

After changing the name once and for further addition if you want the same name to be added then you might have to assign that String to the variable 'name';

Example:

```
changeName(String name){
 for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
  list[i] = name;
 }
}

String name = 'test'; 
List<String> nameList = List<String>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Center(
        child: nameList.length == 0
            ? Text('0')
            : Column(
                children: nameList
                    .map(
                      (e) => Text(e),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            nameList.add(name);
          });
        },
        child: Text('add'),
      ),
       RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
           name = 'test2';  //If you want to change the names for future 
                            //values
           changeName(name);          
          });
        },
        child: Text('changeName'),
      )
    ],
  ),
```